# How to disable orientation change when dialog popped up?

Tags: android

Just use DatePicker Dialog, when you change orientation on the pop up dialog, it will give you an error. How can you disable orientation change?

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private Task mTask;
    private static final String DIALOG_DATE = "Date";
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        int year;
        int month;
        int day;

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);



        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

override show() inside your DialogFramgent, and when it is invoked disable the orientation of your Activity. Let your DilagFragment implements the DismissListener, and when the onDismiss is called, re enable the orientation

```
@Override
public void show(FragmentManager fm, String tag) {
 getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
 super.show(fm, tag);
}
```